# Trying to connect react to redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been playing with React for a while and trying to avoid the headache of Redux as long as I possibly could. Now I am working on a project which uses Redux and need help.

I've for sidebar to open and close as I thought it would be an easy task but here's the mess I have made:

MenuSide.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './MenuSide.scss';
import data from './MenuData';

import toggleVisibility from './MenuSideActions';

import Accordion from '../Accordion/Accordion';

class MenuSide extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      visible: true
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

  }

  handleClick() {
      this.props.dispatch(toggleVisibility());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar-container">

        <div className={this.props.visible ? 'sidebar large-3 columns' : 'hide' }>
          <div className={this.props.visible ? 'button-open' : 'hide'} onClick={() => {
            this.handleClick()
          }}>

          </div>
          <div className="sidebar-header">
            <h3 className="id-header-text">8374995867</h3>
            { /*optional message*/ }
            { data.messsage ? <h5>data.message</h5> : "" }
          </div>
          <Accordion/>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => {
          this.handleClick()
        }} className={!this.props.visible ? 'open-side-menu-button' : 'hide' }></div>
      </div>

    );

  }

}

MenuSide.propTypes = {};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    visible: state.visible
  }
};



export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MenuSide);
```

MenuSideActions.js

```
export default function toggleVisibility () {
  return {type: "TOGGLE_VISIBILITY", visible: visible}
}
```

MenuSideReducer.js

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
  visible: true
};

const toggleVisibility  = (state, action) => {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {visible: !action.visible});
};

export default (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "TOGGLE_VISIBILITY": {
      return toggleVisibility(state, action);
    }
  }
  return state;
};
```

I'm getting an error saying "visible" is not defined but I have no idea where I am tripping!

Any guidance would be appreciated, this Redux thing looks useful if I could use it :-P

Comment: `return {type: "TOGGLE_VISIBILITY", visible: visible}` probably from here. Shouldn't `visible` be a parameter of that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the error you are getting is probably from here:

```
export default function toggleVisibility () {
  return {type: "TOGGLE_VISIBILITY", visible: visible} // <<<---
}
```

There is no `visible` variable in this scope - did you intend to make it a parameter? The best solution would be to only have the toggle logic inside your reducer (as you already have). Therefore rewrite the action as:

```
export default function toggleVisibility () {
  return {type: "TOGGLE_VISIBILITY"}
}
```

And the reducer:

```
const toggleVisibility  = (state, action) => {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {visible: !state.visible});
};
```

Furthermore you should modify your connect call and pass a second function to map `dispatch` to props:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    visible: state.visible
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        toggle: () => {
            dispatch(toggleVisibility());
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MenuSide);
```

Then modify the `handleClick()`:

```
handleClick() {
    this.props.toggle();
}
```

Comment: Ah okay now I have no errors but my state is constantly stuck on visible: true?

Comment: Ok so the question is where you want to keep the logic for "toggling". Currently it is stuck since the reducer itself also inverts the value for the visibility. I'll modify my answer to reflect keeping the logic in the reducer.